# Error while trying to install .net 3.1 code on ubuntu container running on 18.04

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, docker-container

I am new to Docker and I am trying my hands at it.

I have an image that is on ubuntu 18.04 running an interactive container with it.
I want to install .net3.1 core on it and commit it to my image.

referring to this link[link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/install/linux-ubuntu) to install the .net core.
I have installed .net core in one of my EC2, machines similar way.

Here is a commend that I am running

```
wget https://packages.microsoft.com/config/ubuntu/18.04/packages-microsoft-prod.deb -O packages-microsoft-prod.deb
```

I am getting an error below:

```
--2021-01-08 11:38:46--  https://packages.microsoft.com/config/ubuntu/18.04/packages-microsoft-prod.deb
Resolving packages.microsoft.com (packages.microsoft.com)... failed: Temporary failure in name resolution.
wget: unable to resolve host address 'packages.microsoft.com'
```

Could some one help me out with this and make me install .net core in this container?